# partial view does not recognize a function in a js class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a class for creating chart in js, I added the source in my main view and used it. In the main view I add sources like this:

```html
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/kendo.all.min.js")"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CreateChart.js")"></script>
```

The function name is `createChart()` which is inside `createChart` class,it works everywhere in the main view when I call it,but in the partial view I need to call this function:

```html
@model string 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/KndoTst/kendo.all.min.js")"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CreateChart.js")"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
  var dtDrpVals = new selectedDateDrpdnVal();   
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("reductionValues","Dashbrd")",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "regionalManager":dtDrpVals.drpValue,
      "dtFrom":dtDrpVals.fromDate,
      "dtTo":dtDrpVals.toDate}),
    success: function (result) {
      createChart(chartID, result);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

When it reaches the line `createChart()`, it does not recognize kendo chart, but library is added up there!

Comment: Can you show the `CreateChart.js`? Is function `createChart` defined in global scope?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials (only the main view or layout).

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes,but for sake of testing,it doesnt work in either way

Comment: @Satpal in the main view,its inside the createChart class

Comment: Make sure the script file is being loaded properly. have you checked the Network tab ?